# Permission denied (publickey). when disabling PasswordAuthentication

Tags: ssh, deployment, github-actions, cicd

I have 2 machines:

- Windows machine with `WSL` installed, that serves as a **client**.
- Ubuntu machine, with a `test-user` user, that serves as a **server**.

Both computer are on the same **network**.

---

On the Ubuntu computer, what I did:

- I used `ssh-keygen` to generate two keys, I copied the **id_rsa** file to the `WSL`.
- Make sure the ssh service is up, with `systemctl status ssh`.

---

On the WSL, what I did:

- Copied the **id_rsa** file as **key**.
- Changed the permission of the **key** file with `chmod 600 key`.
- Connect to the server machine :

> ssh -i key test-user@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX

This works well, but it also ask me the password of the user.

> hamuto@DESKTOP-HLSFHPR:~$ ssh  -i key test-user@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
> test-user@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX's password:

The problem with this thing is, that with `Github Actions`, I can't enter the password.

So I changed the file  `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` in the server:

```
# To disable tunneled clear text passwords, change to no here!
PasswordAuthentication no <-- I've changed that to no, and uncomment the line
#PermitEmptyPasswords no
```

When I retry to connect with ssh:

> hamuto@DESKTOP-HLSFHPR:~$ ssh  -i key test-user@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
> test-user@XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX: Permission denied (publickey).

### Why is that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After days of research, I found the solution:

- First thing first, I needed to understand that you only need one pair of key, generated on the **Ubuntu** server.
- In the server, you have to copy the `id_rsa.pub` in the `~/.ssh/authorized_keys`.
- Set the permission correctly:

```
chown -R username:username /home/username/.ssh
chmod 700 /home/username/.ssh
chmod 600 /home/username/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

- Change the value of `PubkeyAuthentication` in the file `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` to yes and uncomment it.
- Copy the private `id_rsa` key, to the client. Set the permission to `600`.

You can connect to the server:

> ssh -i ~/.ssh/id_rsa test-user@XXX.XXX.XX.XX

Now it works.